# Creating a service that streams video: Where to start?

Tags: web-services, video, stream, streaming, video-streaming

I want to create a service that streams live traffic video to either a client browser or a client processor (which will actually process the video).  I want *real* video, not just images that update periodically.  Assume I know the basic concepts of web design (both front and back end).  But assume I know nothing about streaming media.

Can someone point me in the direction to get started?

I need information concerning software, frameworks (especially if it's compatible with Ruby on Rails), encoders, converters, protocols, ...  - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like tokbox?

http://www.tokbox.com/

I havent personally used it. However I have visited an on line video podcast that uses this technology. Good quality streaming.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, although I'll probably need something that is closer to metal than this.  Some of the clients will be doing video processing.  I better amend my question a bit.